# Keep vim buffer view at end of file

Tags: vim

In vim (7.4) I have a window of a buffer that is updated by a vim plugin (Pyclewn). If I close that window and reopen it, the window doesn't "auto-scroll" (for lack of a better term) to the end of that buffer automatically anymore. I don't know if this is normally done by the plugin and I am breaking that by closing the window.

How can I force a window to always view the last lines of a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

This should help out, add it your vimrc

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ exe "normal! G"
endif
```

This however will cause any buffer that opens to have the cursor at the last line

If the file you keep trying to open has a specific filetype ex: .log

Then use the following to avoid every buffer opening at the last line

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd BufReadPost *.log
    \ exe "normal! G"
endif
```

See also

```
:h autocmd-patterns
```